# SugarORM(android)

Tags: android, sugarorm

Подскажите,когда я выполняю вот такой код:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < response.body().size(); i++) { // Узнаем колличество постов
                ArrayList<PostModelORM> postORM = new ArrayList<>();
                postORM.add(new PostModelORM(
                        Integer.parseInt(response.body().get(i).getIdPost()),
                        response.body().get(i).getGuid().getRendered(),
                        response.body().get(i).getDate(),
                        response.body().get(i).getTitle().getRendered(),
                        response.body().get(i).getContent().getRendered(),
                        response.body().get(i).getExcerpt().getRendered(),
                        response.body().get(i).getCategroiesMass()));
                SugarRecord.saveInTx(postORM);}
```

При повторном вызове цикла данные будут добавлены либо затерты новыми?

Ибо консоль мне выдает что они добавляются при каждом вызове цикла

> I/Sugar: PostModelORM saved : 381
>   I/Sugar: PostModelORM saved : 382
>   I/Sugar: PostModelORM saved : 383
>   I/Sugar: PostModelORM saved : 384

Как можно сделать так чтобы при повторном вызове цикла данные удалялись и записывались новые ,чтобы потом бд не превратилась в зоопарк

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А так не пробовали?

```
ArrayList<PostModelORM> postORM = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i = 0; i < response.body().size(); i++) { // Узнаем колличество постов
     postORM.add(new PostModelORM(
                        Integer.parseInt(response.body().get(i).getIdPost()),
                        response.body().get(i).getGuid().getRendered(),
                        response.body().get(i).getDate(),
                        response.body().get(i).getTitle().getRendered(),
                        response.body().get(i).getContent().getRendered(),
                        response.body().get(i).getExcerpt().getRendered(),
                        response.body().get(i).getCategroiesMass()));
                }           

SugarRecord.saveInTx(postORM);
```